# Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'not authorized

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to connect to MongoDB via Java Apachebeam MongoDbIO connector, getting a "not authorized" error.

The same connection details are working for Python and able to retrieve the data.

Any suggestions would be helpful

**Error:**

021-06-23 17:59:09.041 CESTError message from worker: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'not authorized on test-direkt-dev to execute command { splitVector: "test-direkt-dev.taskLog", keyPattern: { _id: 1 }, force: false, maxChunkSize: 21, $db: "test-direkt-dev", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1624463948, 23), signature: { hash: BinData(0, C92C5EEC1265B01EDB9B51DFC24BAB98D85EAE0D), keyId: 6911535624117813250 } }, lsid: { id: UUID("05eedc7a-f719-49b5-8c53-3d520dc772c4") }, $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }' on server 172.29.156.26:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1624463948, "i" : 31 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on test-direkt-dev to execute command { splitVector: "test-direkt-dev.taskLog", keyPattern: { _id: 1 }, force: false, maxChunkSize: 21, $db: "test-direkt-dev", $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1624463948, 23), signature: { hash: BinData(0, C92C5EEC1265B01EDB9B51DFC24BAB98D85EAE0D), keyId: 6911535624117813250 } }, lsid: { id: UUID("05eedc7a-f719-49b5-8c53-3d520dc772c4") }, $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1624463948, "i" : 31 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "ySxe7BJlsB7bm1HfwkurmNherg0=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6911535624117813250" } } } }

**Code:**

```
return pipeline.apply(MongoDbIO.read()
                       .withUri("mongodb://testuser:testpass1@88.200.92.195:27017")
                               .withDatabase("test-direkt-dev")
                               .withCollection("taskLog"));
```

Thanks for the update.

As per documentation,
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/mongodb/MongoDbIO.Read.html
need to pass the database name  "/database name" if the username:password@ syntax is used.

```
  return pipeline.apply(MongoDbIO.read()
        .withUri("mongodb://testuser:testpass1@88.200.92.195:27017/test-direkt-dev")
    .withDatabase("test-direkt-dev")
    .withCollection("taskLog"));
```

This time, I am getting the following error :

"org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mongodb.MongoDbIO$BoundedMongoDbSource.$closeResource(MongoDbIO.java:407) at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.mongodb.MongoDbIO$BoundedMongoDbSource.split(MongoDbIO.java:537) ... 15 more Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server 88.200.92.195:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1624636024, "i" : 24 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1624636024, "i" : 24 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "8a1nBS/Wmd5z1SHqhLKnW7Y/g7I=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6911535624117813250" } } } } at"

Answer (score 0):

If the same details work in the Python SDK, I suggest filing a bug with the steps to reproduce the problem. I did not find [any existing bug for Java's MongoDbIO](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?filter=12346475&jql=project%20%3D%20BEAM%20AND%20component%20%3D%20io-java-mongodb%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC). See https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/ for information about how to file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

[splitVector](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/splitVector/#splitvector) is a MongoDB internal command that should not be called from a driver.